# Using a batch program to search for a keyword and copy offset content to a file

Tags: windows, batch-file, search, offset

I am trying to figure out a way to code a windows batch program that will search a file for a keyword.
Every time the keyword is found, the line that is 3 lines below the content is found, and letter 5 to 12 is copied to a file.
Using the example input file below:

```
example_input.txt 
bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla
bla keyword bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla
bla content1bla bla
bla keyword bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla
bla content2bla bla
```

I wish to get the following output file

```
example_ouput.txt 
content1
content2
```

The input file will never have another keyword before content offset is reached.
It may be necessary to copy multiple content items per keyword.

I have searched and found a couple of single elements of this process, but have been unable to combine these to a working script. I would therefore highly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a very efficient program called FindRepl.bat designed to find strings in files in advanced ways. Its use is straightforward, as you can see in the example session below:

```
C:\> type input.txt
bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla
bla keyword bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla
bla content1bla bla
bla keyword bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla
bla content2bla bla

C:\> rem To use FindRepl, redirect to it the input file and insert the search word:

C:\> < input.txt FindRepl "keyword"
bla keyword bla bla
bla keyword bla bla

C:\> rem The /Offset switch allows to define blocks of lines based on found lines:

C:\> < input.txt FindRepl "keyword" /O:+3:+3
bla content1bla bla
bla content2bla bla

C:\> rem Then evaluate a regular expression over such /Block of lines
C:\> rem and show the matched subexpression enclosed in parentheses via /$ switch
C:\> rem (the regexp format is described in noodlesstillalive answer above)

C:\> < input.txt FindRepl "keyword" /O:+3:+3 /B:".{4}(.{8})" /$:1
 "content1"
 "content2"

C:\> rem Quotes are standard when "/$:1" switch is used, so just eliminate they:

C:\> for /F %a in ('^< input.txt FindRepl "keyword" /O:+3:+3 /B:".{4}(.{8})" /$:1') do @echo %~a
content1
content2
```

You may also achieve a very large set of different find and find&replace operations using FindRepl.bat program; you may download it from [this site](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only content0 to content9 this regexp would work.

"Content[0-9]"

```
Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
Set regEx = New RegExp
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set srcfile = fso.GetFile(objArgs(0))
        If err.number = 0 then Set TS = srcFile.OpenAsTextStream(1, 0)
        Src=ts.readall
        regEx.Pattern = objArgs(1) 
        regEx.IgnoreCase = True
        regEx.Global = True
        Set Matches = regEx.Execute(Src)
        For Each Match in Matches
            wscript.echo Match.Value
        Next
```

To use

```
cscript //nologo script.vbs "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Callback.txt" "Share[bcd]"
Shared
Shared
```

Redirect if you want it in a file.

Special characters and sequences are used in writing patterns for regular expressions. The following table describes and gives an example of the characters and sequences that can be used.

**Character**  **Description**

> \ 
>    Marks the next character as either a special character or a literal. For example, "n" matches the character "n". "\n" matches a newline character. The sequence "\" matches "\" and "(" matches "(".
>
> ^ 
>    Matches the beginning of input.
>
> $ 
>    Matches the end of input.
>
> - Matches the preceding character zero or more times. For example, "zo*" matches either "z" or "zoo".
> - Matches the preceding character one or more times. For example, "zo+" matches "zoo" but not "z".
>
> ? 
>    Matches the preceding character zero or one time. For example, "a?ve?" matches the "ve" in "never".
>
> .
>    Matches any single character except a newline character.
>
> (pattern)
>    Matches pattern and remembers the match. The matched substring can be retrieved from the resulting Matches collection, using Item [0]...[n]. To match parentheses characters ( ), use "(" or ")".
>
> x|y
>    Matches either x or y. For example, "z|wood" matches "z" or "wood". "(z|w)oo" matches "zoo" or "wood".
>
> {n}
>    n is a nonnegative integer. Matches exactly n times. For example, "o{2}" does not match the "o" in "Bob," but matches the first two o's in "foooood".
>
> {n,} 
>    n is a nonnegative integer. Matches at least n times. For example, "o{2,}" does not match the "o" in "Bob" and matches all the o's in "foooood." "o{1,}" is equivalent to "o+". "o{0,}" is equivalent to "o*".
>
> { n , m } 
>    m and n are nonnegative integers. Matches at least n and at most m times. For example, "o{1,3}" matches the first three o's in "fooooood." "o{0,1}" is equivalent to "o?".
>
> [ xyz ] 
>    A character set. Matches any one of the enclosed characters. For example, "[abc]" matches the "a" in "plain".
>
> [^ xyz ] 
>    A negative character set. Matches any character not enclosed. For example, "[^abc]" matches the "p" in "plain".
>
> [ a-z ] 
>    A range of characters. Matches any character in the specified range. For example, "[a-z]" matches any lowercase alphabetic character in the range "a" through "z".
>
> [^ m-z ] 
>    A negative range characters. Matches any character not in the specified range. For example, "[m-z]" matches any character not in the range "m" through "z".
>
> \b 
>    Matches a word boundary, that is, the position between a word and a space. For example, "er\b" matches the "er" in "never" but not the "er" in "verb".
>
> \B 
>    Matches a non-word boundary. "ea*r\B" matches the "ear" in "never early".
>
> \d 
>    Matches a digit character. Equivalent to [0-9].
>
> \D 
>    Matches a non-digit character. Equivalent to [^0-9].
>
> \f 
>    Matches a form-feed character.
>
> \n 
>    Matches a newline character.
>
> \r 
>    Matches a carriage return character.
>
> \s 
>    Matches any white space including space, tab, form-feed, etc. Equivalent to "[ \f\n\r\t\v]".
>
> \S 
>    Matches any nonwhite space character. Equivalent to "[^ \f\n\r\t\v]".
>
> \t 
>    Matches a tab character.
>
> \v 
>    Matches a vertical tab character.
>
> \w 
>    Matches any word character including underscore. Equivalent to "[A-Za-z0-9_]".
>
> \W 
>    Matches any non-word character. Equivalent to "[^A-Za-z0-9_]".
>
> \num 
>    Matches num, where num is a positive integer. A reference back to remembered matches. For example, "(.)\1" matches two consecutive identical characters.
>
> \ n 
>    Matches n, where n is an octal escape value. Octal escape values must be 1, 2, or 3 digits long. For example, "\11" and "\011" both match a tab character. "\0011" is the equivalent of "\001" & "1". Octal escape values must not exceed 256. If they do, only the first two digits comprise the expression. Allows ASCII codes to be used in regular expressions.
>
> \xn
>    Matches n, where n is a hexadecimal escape value. Hexadecimal escape values must be exactly two digits long. For example, "\x41" matches "A". "\x041" is equivalent to "\x04" & "1". Allows ASCII codes to be used in regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. However, I may have expressed myself ambiguously. the item "content*" may be any string. The defining property of the content that I try to extract is that it is 3 lines below "keyword", and that it is letters 5 to 12 in this line. On top of it, I would prefer to have everythging in a .bat file, since I have never touched vb. :)

Comment: You can't, in any reasonable way, do this in batch. But a cinch in vbscript. And I gave you a program that worked in batch with you only being required to copy and paste it. You definition is still unclear, where does the keyword come from? Pulling out + 3 lines (not easy in batch and makes unreadable code), 5-12 chars easy in vbscript (and also batch), but what is keyword and where does it come from?

Comment: Hi again,Items "keyword" and "content" are placeholders.

Comment: What I try try (unsucessfully) to describe is a program that goes through a textfile line for line. For each line, it scans for the keyword. When the keyword is found, it goes 3 lines down, extracts a string containing char 5 to 12 of that line, and puts this string in an output file. The program then resumes to scan for the keyword. Starting either at the line below the line where it found the last keyword, or starting at the line below the one where it extracted the string. -Whichever is easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
    Line=Inp.readline
    If Instr(Line,"keyword") <> true then 
        Line = Inp.Readline
        Line = Inp.Readline
        Line = Mid(Inp.Readline, 5, 7)
        Outp.writeline Line 
Loop
```

This one uses redirection.

```
cscript //nologo script.vbs <inputfile.txt >outputfile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! After adding End If above Loop, the script outputs data. However, it appears that the data output is not the data offset from the line with the located keyword..  i am digging further.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. Problem solved!
I closed the If then, and changed the condition from true to 0, and I am now getting a sane output.

The working script looks as follows:

```
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
    Line=Inp.readline
    If Instr(Line,"keyword") <> 0 then 
        Line = Inp.Readline
        Line = Inp.Readline
        Line = Mid(Inp.Readline, 5, 7)
        Outp.writeline Line
    End If
Loop
```

The executing syntax is as follows (no changes were required):

```
cscript //nologo script.vbs <inputfile.txt >outputfile.txt
```

Thank you Noodles!